# Strange behaviour with templates and #defines

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2008, syntax, c-preprocessor

I have the following definitions:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Test2
{
public:
    static int hello() { return 0; }
};

template<typename T>
class Test1
{
public:
    static int hello() { return 0; }
};

#define VERIFY_R(call) { if (call == 0) printf("yea");}
```

With these, I try to compile the following:

```
VERIFY_R( Test1<int>::hello() );
```

this compiles fine

```
VERIFY_R( (Test2<int,int>::hello()) );
```

this also compiles fine, notice the parentheses around the call.

```
VERIFY_R( Test2<int,int>::hello() );
```

This, without the parentheses produces a warning and several syntax errors:

```
warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'VERIFY_R'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found
```

What's going on here?
This happens with VS2008 SP1.

Comment: That probably happens because whatever you put inside the () of VERIFY_R is inserted LITERALLY. Try changing second "call" in your macro to "(call)".

Comment: That won't help, it's a macro issue. Funny thing is: that's why `BOOST_FOREACH` can be a headache for newbies :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comma inside a macro can be ambiguous: an extra set of parentheses (your second example) is one way of disambiguating. Consider a macro

```
#define VERIFY(A, B) { if ( (A) && (B) ) printf("hi"); }
```

then you could write `VERIFY( foo<bar, x> y )`.

Another way of disambiguating is with

```
typedef Test1<int,int> TestII;
VERIFY_R( TestII::hello() );
```

Answer (score 5):

The preprocessor is a dumb text replacement tool that knows nothing about C++. It interprets

```
VERIFY_R( Test1<int,int>::hello() );
```

as

```
VERIFY_R( (Test1<int), (int>::hello()) );
```

which calls `VERIFY_R` with too many parameters. As you noted, additional parentheses fix this:

```
VERIFY_R( (Test1<int,int>::hello()) );
```

The question remains, however, why you need the preprocessor anyway. The macro you used in your question could just as well be an `inline` function. If you real code doesn't do anything requiring the preprocessor, try to get rid of macros. They just cause pain.

Answer (score 4):

The comma in `<int, int>` is treated as an argument separator for the macro, rather than for the template. The compiler therefore thinks you're calling `VERIFY_R` with two arguments (`Test1<int` and `int>::hello()`), when it requires only one. You need to use [variadic macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415%28VS.80%29.aspx) to expand everything supplied to the macro:

```
#define VERIFY_R(...) { if ((__VA_ARGS__) == 0) printf("yea");}
```

It is generally a good idea to wrap macro arguments in parentheses, as well, to prevent other kinds of weird substitution errors.

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor doesn't know that `<` and `>` are supposed to be brackets, so it interprets the expression as two macro arguments, `Test1<int` and `int>::hello()`, separated by the `,`. As you say, it can be fixed by surrounding the entire expression with parentheses, which the preprocessor does recognise as brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an error in your reporting here or the actual problem, but your last VERIFY_R is still referencing Test1, rather than Test2.